# Exception when trying to parse a LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I am using the following timestamp format:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS
```

The following method works fine:

```
public static String formatTimestamp(final Timestamp timestamp, final String format) {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    return timestamp.toLocalDateTime().format(formatter);
}
```

And, when I pass in a Timestamp with that format string, it returns, for example:

```
20170925142051591
```

I then require to map from that string to a Timestamp again, essentially the reverse operation. I know that I can use a `SimpleDateFormat` and its `parse()` method, but I'd prefer to stick to `java.time` style formatting, if possible.

I wrote this (rather hacky) bit of code, which works with some formats, but not with this particular one:

```
public static Timestamp getTimestamp(final String text, final String format, final boolean includeTime) {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    final TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(text);
    if (includeTime) {
        final LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
        return DateTimeUtil.getTimestamp(localDateTime);
    } else {
        final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.from(temporalAccessor);
        return DateTimeUtil.getTimestamp(localDate);
    }
}
```

It fails on the second line, at the `formatter.parse(text);` part.

Stack Trace:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20170925142051591' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:477)
    at com.csa.core.DateTimeUtil.main(DateTimeUtil.java:169)
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want without utilising `SimpleDateFormat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085

The link above also provides the workaround: using a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with a `java.time.temporal.ChronoField` for the milliseconds field:

```
String text = "20170925142051591";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date/time
    .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    // milliseconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
// now it works
formatter.parse(text);
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to parse this using only `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String)`.

Comment: @ManoDestra In the bug page, the status is "resolved" and Fix version is 9, so my guess is that it should be fixed in JDK 9. But I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @ManoDestra I've tested with [Java 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) and it's fixed (it worked with `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS` pattern)

Comment: Superb. Thanks for that :)